# How to get company's API App ID/Secret for Quip Public API?

Tags: liveapps, quip

Currently I'm developing the live app to integrate my service into Quip. I need to interact with Quip API from the back-end of my application.

Every Quip workspace has it's own API applications with Client ID/Secrets.

So if my Live App will be able in the AppExchange,

> **How should I get my customers' ClientID/Secrets to access to their data via Quip API?**

For example, in Salesforce I can use single Connected App with it's credentials to access to organization's data of my customers. But in Quip every company should create it's own application for this purpose.

If the users should provide me with their credentials via email - it's a big problem, because the first their experience with the live app will be negative.